# VPN On - Allow Port Forwarding?

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding

How can I allow incoming connections on a Windows 7 machine that is connected to VPN? I have some services listening on certain ports that I have forwarded from my router. When the VPN is disconnected, I can connect to these services from my internal network as well as from the Internet without issue. When I connect my VPN however, I am still able to access the ports from my internal network, but not remotely.

There is an option in the VPN settings to Use Default Gateway on remote network. The thing is I want this option enabled so all my traffic is routed through the VPN, but I want incoming connections to be allowed on my internal network IP from the Internet. Is there some hybrid way to set this up with routing?

I did find that adding a new route with the route add command for my external IP resolves this problem, but then I would have to add a new route every time I get a new IP at a hotspot, etc. Is there any better way to do this?